# Нужно разное название во внешних ключах MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть две таблицы, которые относятся к главной связью многие ко многим. Для каждой выделена соединяющая. Я правильно понял, что при создании внешнего ключа, нельзя одинаково именовать внешние ключи, которые относятся к одному и тому же полю в главной таблице? В данном случае `scientist_id`.

И ещё вопрос:

Как создать Primary Key из двух полей, чтобы не создавать новое? Просто отметить галочкой Pk на обоих полях? В `summary_field` `scientist_id` и `field_id` к примеру?

[image: Скриншот =)]

Comment: Ответ: 1 - да, нельзя, называйте по разному. Иначе как потом sql отлит их, если один из них вы захотите удалить, например. В `drop` же только имя констраинта обычно задается. 2 - В sql нет понятия 'галочек' ибо это язык, который пишется просто буквами (`crate table ... primary key ...`) В большинстве интерфейсов к нему - да, две галочки, просто проверьте это в вашем интерфейсе, который вы не указали в вопросе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Столбцы в разных таблицах могут называться одинаково. В этом нет криминала.
Не знаю, каким интерфейсом вы пользуетесь, но для создания составного ключа попробуйте выделить все столбцы, входящие в PK, и затем действуйте как и при создании простого.

Напишите на SQL:

```
Alter table summary_scientific_work
add constraint PKkk Primary key(scientist_id, scientist_work_id);
```

Comment: А два поля, которые используются в внешнем ключе не могут стать составным первичным ключом? 
При попытке сделать ключи scientist_id и scientist_work_id в таблице "summary_scientist_work"  выходит ошибка: Cannot change column 'scientist_id': used in a foreign key constraint 'scientist_id_fk'

Comment: @ZhiV Могут!  Это что-то не так с вашим дизайнером БД или делаете что-то не то.

Comment: @ZhiV  Думаю вам надо удалить фореджн, пересоздать первичный ключ и создать фореджен заново, уже ссылающийся на составной первичный